# How to get a border radius on a rectangle using gd library

Tags: php, image, gd

I am using gd library code to create a rectangle. How could I get a border radius on my rectangle in php.

Here is my code so for:

```
    $bg_color="5465FF";
$text_color="61FF66";
$button_width = 150;
$button_height =50;
$textdisplay="text";

$r_bg = hexdec("0x".substr($bg_color,0,2));
$g_bg = hexdec("0x".substr($bg_color,2,2));
$b_bg = hexdec("0x".substr($bg_color,4,2));

$r_bgt = hexdec("0x".substr($text_color,0,2));
$g_bgt = hexdec("0x".substr($text_color,2,2));
$b_bgt = hexdec("0x".substr($text_color,4,2));
header('content-type: image/png');      
$image = imagecreate($button_width, $button_height); 
$blue = imagecolorallocate($image, $r_bg, $g_bg, $b_bg); 
$red = imagecolorallocate($image, $r_bgt, $g_bgt, $b_bgt);  
imagestring($image,18,0,0,$textdisplay,$red);       
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

I would like my rectangle to look something like this:

[image]

Comment: You could use this function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilledarc.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$image = roundCorners($image, 20);
```

Answer (score -1):

`border-radius : 10px;` (maybe - try this)

Comment: He asked for a answer in PHP not CSS.